# Set Intent to back key in TabActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have three Activities - A B and C, of which B is a **Tab Activity**. 
Activity A is launched first, and B is launched from A. I finish Activity A when B is launched using this code

```
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   this.finish();
}
```

Now I want to launch Activity C when back key is pressed in B.

I tried overriding back key using this code

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { this.getParent().onBackPressed();
}
```

This doesn't Help as the Parent Activity is finished while launching the Child Activity. What actually happens when I press back key is that the Activity exits to the Home screen.

I tried overriding the back key and setting an Intent to it

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backIntent = new Intent();
    backIntent.setClass(this, main.class);
    startActivity(backIntent);
}
```

This also doesn't help me. 
What could be a possible solution to this problem, How can I launch Activity C when back key is pressed ?

Comment: try....  backIntent.setClass(this, C.class);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should not finish the activity A when Activity A stops this is completely wrong approach instead of it you have to finish activity when you start activity B.

For example

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Now you want to start the activity C when user press the back button so use the below code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, C.class);
    startActivity(backIntent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried this. The problem still persists. The activity C is not launched

Answer (score 1):

You have to override onKeyDown

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        //Do your code here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

This will be called when user pressed Device Hard Back Button.

To navigate to next activity:
    StartActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),main.class));

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Override the below method and import event.....

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

   if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK)
   {
      //Write your intent or other code here
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```